# 「言ってたら」What is the meaning behind the "te-tara" form?

Tags: conditionals

This has just come up in my textbook, but not too sure what the meaning is.

```
「～」と言ってたら～
```

I can see that it is a 'te' conjugation of 言う, but then followed by the conditional 'tara'. I've not before seen such a 'double conjugation' and my grammar dictionary is as useless as ever!

Is it simply the same as 言ったら, or is it slightly different?

Comment: Are you familiar with ～ている? It can be shortened to ～てる.

Comment: [**てたら in action**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOs9hnn1l1Y). In this case, the たら would most likely carry the nuance of "when" (準{じゅん}備{び}してたら爆{ばく}発{はつ}した = After 準備, then 爆発した) rather than "if".

Comment: @rhyaeris I think "while preparing" is better than "after preparing" because してたら is progressive. Or does the word "after" mean "progressive"?

Comment: @YuuichiTam Nope, it doesn't. "While", then. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

言ってたら＝言っていたら — Dropping the い from いる in continuous forms is extremely common in spoken Japanese.　話している→話してる　来ています→来てます　報告していました→報告してました　などなどなど

そんなこと**言ってたら**怒られるぜ。"If you go around saying things like that/talking like that, you're going to get in trouble."

It's the conditional form of the continuous form of 言う using いる.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Marc Adler's explanation:

～と言ってたら is used as subjunctive past perfect. For example:

> あの[時]{とき}、あなたが好きと**言ってたら**、[今頃]{いまごろ}私たちは[結婚]{けっこん}していただろう。
>   -- If I had said "I love you" at that time, we would be married now.

---

言ったら means "if I said(say)" or "I said ～ and then".

For example:

> もし私がアメリカに行きたいと**言ったら**、あなたは[反対]{はんたい}する?
>   -- If I said(say) "I want to go to the U.S", would(will) you oppose?

and

> 私がアメリカに行きたいと**言ったら**、彼は[怒]{おこ}った。
>   -- I said "I want to go to the U.S", and then he got angry.